# NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

In this code, how can I use the (name) variable inside of any other function Knowing that the variable is a local variable? I would really love some pointers if you have any, thank you.

```py
def get_Name():
    name = input("What's Your Name? ")
    return f"{name} Is A Male. "
    
def get_Age():
    age = input("What's Your Age? ")
    return f"{name} Is {age} Years Old"
        
get_Name()
get_Age()
```

Comment: You pass it when calling the function.

Comment: You can also make it global variable if multiple functions requires the same variable. But be cautious, since global variables can be accessed throughout the whole program, Data can be modified by any function. Also, those variables would be available till the termination of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def get_name():
    return f"{self.name} Is A Male. "

  def get_age():
    return f"{self.name} Is {self.age} Years Old"

person = Person(
  name=input("What's Your Name? "),
  age=input("What's Your Age? "),
)    
person.get_name()
person.get_age()
```